# Calling Echo inside a function pre-pends echo string to return value in Powershell

Tags: powershell, function, string, echo

I am a Powershell noob and seem to keep getting caught on little weird behaviors like this.  Here is some test code:

```
 function EchoReturnTest(){
     echo "afdsfadsf"
     return "blah"
 }

 $variable = EchoReturnTest
 echo ("var: " + $variable)
```

Running this script generates this as output: "var: afdsfadsf blah"

Why does the function not just return the string "blah"?

Comment: just a guess, but it looks like STDOUT (ie what echo is printing to) and the return value are being dumped into the same stream. You might be able to force them to be separate by telling echo to print to STDERR: echo "afdsfadsf" 1>&2;

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, PowerShell functions return all uncaptured "output". You can capture output by assigning to a variable and you can ignore output by redirecting to `$null` e.g.:

```
$arrayList.Add("hi") > $null
```

This would normally output something like 0 (the index where "hi" was added) but because we redirected to $null, the output is disregarded.

Second, `echo` is just an alias for "Write-Output" which writes the corresponding object to the output stream.  `return "blah"` is just a convenience which is equivalent to:

```
Write-Output "blah"
return
```

So your function implementation is equivalent to this:

```
function EchoReturnTest(){  
    Write-Output "afdsfadsf"  
    Write-Output "blah"
    return
}
```

If you want to "see" some info on the host console without it being considered part of the "output" of a function then use Write-Host e.g.:

```
function EchoReturnTest(){  
    Write-Host "afdsfadsf"  
    return "blah"
}
```

Also, if you have no parameters then you don't need the parens at the end of the function name e.g. `function EchoReturnTest { return 'blah' }`.

Comment: Possible Typo: Isn't echo an alias for "write-output"?

Comment: Yep.  WriteObject is what you use when writing a cmdlet in C# where I've been spending my time lately.  Kind of wish they would have kept the names consistent.  :-)

Comment: Is there a way to override the behaviour, so the uncaptured values are not returned? E.g. if I want to be specific that whatever happened in the function, only a specific value is returned?