# Powershell external program as variable

Tags: variables, powershell

I just started with powershell. And created a script to monitor my server.
But, I also need to monitor my harddisks and raid configuration from my server. This only can be done with software from HP.

So what I want:
I have a command line utility from HP, which I can use to monitor the array and disks.
when I start this utility, I get this:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Compaq\Hpacucli\Bin> .\hpacucli.exe controller slot=3 physicaldrive "1I:0:1 (port 1I:box 0:bay  1, 750 GB)" show status | out-host 
physicaldrive 1I:0:1 (port 1I:box 0:bay 1, 750 GB): OK
```

I just want this output as a variable to use it further in my script.

How can this be done.

I tried:

```
$disk1 = "c:\program files (x86)\Compaq\hpacucli\bin\hpacucli.exe controller slot=3 physicaldrive "1I:0:1 (port 1I:box 0:bay  1, 750 GB)" show status | out-host"
```

But this was not working

So I just want to have `physicaldrive 1I:0:1 (port 1I:box 0:bay 1, 750 GB): OK` as variable.

I hope someone can help me. So I can learn to use powershell further.

Thanks allready. dennis

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the `out-host` cmdlet as it is consuming the exe's output e.g.:

```
$disk1 = .\hpacucli.exe controller slot=3 physicaldrive "1I:0:1 (port 1I:box 0:bay 1, 750 GB)" show status
```

With PowerShell, keep in mind that anytime you invoke a pipeline and there is output, it will go to the output stream where it can be captured by a variable (like above) or get displayed to the screen if the output is not captured.  When you pipe to `Out-Host`, it bypasses normal output and displays the input "directly" to the screen. That's why you can't capture the data to a variable.

In a function, this is a bit different than traditional languages because every statement that produces output that isn't captured to a variable (or redirected to $null) will produce output for that function.  This can be surprising to many first time PowerShell users when their functions return more than they expected.  Look at the [accepted answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158786/calling-echo-inside-a-function-pre-pends-echo-string-to-return-value-in-powershe) for more details.

Comment: I still cannot figure it out.

Comment: just don't understand how to get it right. I would like when i type: $disk1 = .\hpacucli.exe controller slot=3 physicaldrive "1I:0:1 (port 1I:box 0:bay 1, 750 GB)" show status, and then type $disk1, that i get the status of the disks, and not $disk1 = .\hpacucli.exe controller slot=3 physicaldrive "1I:0:1 (port 1I:box 0:bay 1, 750 GB)" show status
as result. I hope someone understands what i mean. Again, i'm totally new to powershell (and scripting in general)